# Search first character in a column PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to search the first character from a column by charlist (bracket expression) but it brings all the column characters although there are customers their names starting with non-letters.

I use PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT name
FROM customs
WHERE name ~* '[a-z]'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also dispense with regular expression matching and simply do:

```
where name < 'a' or name >= '{'
```

`{` is the mysterious character that follows `z` in the ASCII chart.  Note:  For this or any solution, you may need to check whether or not the collation is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP:

> Unlike `LIKE` patterns, a regular expression is allowed to match anywhere within a string, unless the regular expression is explicitly anchored to the beginning or end of the string.
>
> Some examples:
>
> ```
> 'abc' ~ 'abc'    true
> 'abc' ~ '^a'     true
> 'abc' ~ '(b|d)'  true
> 'abc' ~ '^(b|c)' false
> ```

So your condition should be

```
WHERE name ~* '^[a-z]'
```

if you want to match only at the beginning of `name`.